# Batch-adding properties in Python?

Tags: python, properties, lazy-evaluation

In my code I want to create a bunch of lazy variables, however, if any one of them is being queried, the `Load()` function as a whole should be called, which will populate all the underlying lazy variables at once.

Currently my class looks like this:

```
@property
def test1(self):
    if (not self.__test1):
        self.Load()
    return self.__test1

@property
def test2(self):
    if (not self.__test2):
        self.Load()
    return self.__test2

....
```

Since this looks quite ugly if being done on 30+ variables, I was wondering if there is a way to do this prettier in Python, maybe with some smart decorator?

Thank you for your replies

Comment: Is `Load` really the method called for all of them? If `Load` returns the same thing each time, it's not clear why you have multiple properties. If it returns a different value, then it seems like each property is cache for what is otherwise a sequence of calls to the same property.

Comment: The answer is probably "it can be done", but I'm not quite sure how it'd be done off the top of my head. (Metaclass? Class decorator? Descriptors? Implementing a very odd `__getattr__`?)

Comment: Does `self.Load()` set the values of `__test1` et al? Otherwise, how do they get set?

Comment: `self.Load()` returns nothing. Instead it sets all values of the variables at once (it's basically a `cPickle.load()` operation where it's unfeasible to load the individual parts, and much more efficient to load everything at once).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a metaclass to dynamically create all the properties that needs lazy loading. This metaclass gets the property names from a list `lazy_props` defined in your own class, and within `__new__()` generate the properties in your class.

The code is like this:

```
class LazyMeta(type):
    def __new__(cls, clsname, bases, clsdict):
        d = dict(clsdict)
        props = d.get("lazy_props")
        def lazy_load(_attr):
            def wrapped_method(self):
                variable = "_" + _attr
                if not hasattr(self, variable):
                    self.Load()
                return getattr(self, variable)
            return wrapped_method

        for prop in props:
            _method = lazy_load(prop)
            _property = property(_method)
            d[prop] = _property

        return type.__new__(cls, clsname, bases, d)

# Your class uses LazyMeta as metaclass
class LazyClass:
    __metaclass__ = LazyMeta
    lazy_props = ['test1', 'test2']
    def Load(self):
        print "Loading ..."
        self._test1=123
        self._test2=456
```

Now when you instantiate a object of LazyClass:

```
>>> l = LazyClass()
>>> l.test1
Loading ...
123
>>> l.test2
456
```

*Note I used `_test1, _test2` in place of `__test1, __test2`, because python treat variables starting with double underscore specially, and it prevents `getattr()` from working properly.*